# How to add whitelist of tags for Java ESAPI

Tags: java, xss, esapi

We are adding Rich Text Editing to our site, including ability to add youtube videos. But from  the other hand we want to be still secure and prevent XSS/HTML injections. Previously we have used following code for escaping the data:

```
ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML
ESAPI.encoder().encodeForJavaScript
```

And now we have to add some kind of whitelist of allowed tags. Is there is way to implement this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have decided to use Jsoup instead on ESAPI. Now code looks like that:

```java
protected String encodeHtml(String html) {
    return Jsoup.clean(html, getWhitelist());
}

private Whitelist getWhitelist() {
    return new Whitelist()
            .addTags("a", "b", "blockquote", "br", "caption", "cite", "code", "col", "colgroup", "dd", "div", "dl",
                    "dt", "em", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "i", "img", "li", "ol", "p", "pre", "q",
                    "small", "strike", "strong", "sub", "sup", "table", "tbody", "td", "tfoot", "th", "thead",
                    "tr", "u", "ul", "iframe")

            .addAttributes("a", "href", "title").addAttributes("blockquote", "cite")
            .addAttributes("col", "span", "width").addAttributes("colgroup", "span", "width")
            .addAttributes("img", "align", "alt", "height", "src", "title", "width")
            .addAttributes("ol", "start", "type").addAttributes("q", "cite")
            .addAttributes("table", "summary", "width")
            .addAttributes("td", "abbr", "axis", "colspan", "rowspan", "width")
            .addAttributes("th", "abbr", "axis", "colspan", "rowspan", "scope", "width")
            .addAttributes("ul", "type")

            .addProtocols("a", "href", "ftp", "http", "https", "mailto")
            .addProtocols("blockquote", "cite", "http", "https").addProtocols("img", "src", "http", "https")
            .addProtocols("q", "cite", "http", "https");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box.  The only option I see is extending the library. Take a look at `org.owasp.esapi.codecs.HTMLEntityCodec` specifically the method `mkCharacterToEntityMap()`

This is where the codec will tell the encoder class what to escape, and what not to escape.  I'd define your own `Codec`.

You'll then probably have to add a method to/extend the `DefaultEncoder` class so that you can use your codec where you'd like to use it.  Perhaps something like `DefaultEncoder.encodeForHTML(String input, Codec codec)`

If the whitelist needs to be even more configurable, then you'll probably want alter it so you can send in a regex like `"input1|input2|input3"` so the codec would know what to ignore.  You'd probably then want this whitelist configured via `esapi.properties` so your tech support could alter it in production without needing a full redeployment.

Answer (score 0):

The ESAPI [Validator.getValidSafeHTML()](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Validator.html#getValidSafeHTML%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20boolean%29) comes close to giving you want you are looking for. It presently uses AntiSamy under-the-hood. You also may wish to give the [OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project#tab=Main) a shot as well. It's very light weight, has few (may no) dependencies, and is well maintained.

-kevin

Comment: Also, it's not directly in the ESAPI javadoc, but I think you can tweak what you want removed, encoded, etc. via the "antisamy-esapi.xml" configuration file, which should be in the same directory as your ESAPI.properties file.